# Countdown with moment.js

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I'm trying to make a countdown of seconds between the current time since next Monday 00:00 with moment.js.

I have looked at the documentation (http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) but I only arrived to have the days since next Monday, this is the code I try to make work to have the countdown. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
var datetime = $('.datetime'),

//Update countdown
update = function(){
        var now = moment();
            nextmonday = moment().day(1),
            diff = now.diff(nextmonday, 'seconds'),
            hours = Math.floor(diff / 3600),
            diff = diff - hours * 3600,
            minutes = Math.floor(diff / 60),
            seconds = diff - minutes * 60;

        datetime.html(diff);

    };

//If it's Monday do nothing
if (moment().day()!=1){
    update();
    setInterval(update, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You have a typo on the line `var now = moment();`. Replace `;` with `,`
2. You are defining `diff` twice, change the first one to something else like `diffSec`
3. You are probably trying to get the difference to the begging of the day, next monday. Do this with `nextmonday = moment().day(1).startOf('day').add('days',7)`

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jondlm/x4MM6/

Comment: Thanks @Jondlm, it works like a charm, error 1 & 2 was me rewriting the code yesterday night ;) to achieve the 00.00 of this coming Monday you don't need the 'add('days',7), but the rest of the code works perfectly!

Comment: No problem. Funny about the `add('days',7)` bit is that it was needed on Saturday when I wrote the answer, but not today. I think that's because *moment* considers a new week to begin on Sunday. You may want a slightly smarter method of determining `nextmonday`. I would write a small loop that adds a day at a time until it's a monday, then use that. Glad it helped!

Comment: You were totally right, the moment.js assumes that week start on Sunday, so you only need to set iso to start on Monday and voila!                   nextmonday = moment().isoWeekday(1).day(1).startOf('day').add('days',7),

Comment: @AdriánPérez, Aha! That's a great solution, I didn't realize `isoWeekday` worked like that. I'll keep that one in my back pocket.